# Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in java?

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

I managed to successfully compile my code, but I'm not able to execute it. How do I fix this?
scannerTesting is my package and ScannerTesting.java is my main file.

`D:\Java>javac Testing\src\scannerTesting\ScannerTesting.java`

`D:\Java>java Testing\src\scannerTesting\ScannerTesting`
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Testing\src\scannerTesting\ScannerTesting <wrong name: scannerTesting/ScannerTesting>`
.
.
.

Comment: http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/07/21/using-javac-and-java-commands-to-compile-and-launch-java-programs/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
java -cp ./Testing/src scannerTesting.ScannerTesting
```

When you run `java`, it looks for matching classes within its classpath. So what these arguments are doing is add your source folder to the classpath using `-cp`, and specify that the class that should be run is `scannerTesting.ScannerTesting`.

For more information, check out [java cli tool documentation at Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)

Comment: It worked when i went to root. Can you explain the logic behind that?

Comment: I'm kind of new to executing files from command prompt, so I would like an explanation to how the above works.

Comment: I also have a file which needs to be read. Which directory should that be in? Currently it's in the Testing folder but it isn't working. However it executes fine when I'm using eclipse

Comment: Where you run the command matters. You should be in the `Testing` folder when you execute it, then you could specify `-cp` as just `src`. This will set the correct classpath and have the working directory as `Testing`

Comment: Is there a difference between \ and /?

Comment: @Alan `'\'` is used as escape character in a lot of contexts, however Microsoft chose that it will also be the path separator. `/` is universally accepted as the path separator. Running in Windows, there is no difference. However, in other operating systems using `'\'` will be treated as escape character rather than path separator.

Answer (score 0):

scannerTesting is your package name,right?

If so, I suggest you run command "java" under the workspace D:\Java\Testing\src

```
java scannerTesting.ScannerTest
```